# BoxPlot: Hover text customization, “smart” jitter

Tags: javascript, plotly

Two "hover" questions regarding my JavaScript box plot graph:

1) Is there a way to label the individual points with a min, max, 25%, 75%, median, etc. decorator? So, instead of seeing "1.3", it would show "max: 1.3".

2) Since my data's ordering has meaning, is there any way to arrange the jitter by the order in which the data is given? For example, the left-most point (jitter-wise) would be the first point in my data array, and the right-most one would be the last one. (Barring this, I'd take an array-index position decoration on my data point, but the sorted jitter would be cooler imo).

Comment: It would be good to see your code (e.g. a executable jsFiddle or codepen minimum example). Furthermore I not exactly understand what is your goal, maybe you can sketch it with paint

Comment: For #1: When you hover over a number, I'd like to have some text next to the number describing what it is (for example: Today I just get "53" and "91", but what I'd like is: "minimum: 53", and "maximum: 91").

Comment: For #2: If you show all points next to the box plot, some left/right jitter is introduced so that all the points don't get drawn on top of each other.  I'd like to have the left-right order of the points sorted.